# Firebase Functions returns error "Error: Unexpected end of form at Multipart._final"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, busboy

I started using Firebase Functions and ran into a problem. Namely, when I created my API (running locally), deployed to Firebase Functions using `firebase deploy --only functions` and called from my frontend - in the function logs an error is displayed:

> Error: Unexpected end of form
> at Multipart._final (/workspace/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:588:17)
> at callFinal (node:internal/streams/writable:696:27)
> at prefinish (node:internal/streams/writable:725:7)
> at finishMaybe (node:internal/streams/writable:735:5)
> at Multipart.Writable.end (node:internal/streams/writable:633:5)
> at onend (node:internal/streams/readable:693:10)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)

My goal is to receive the file in the API and process it using the `easy-template-x` bibiotech. When I used `multer` for this, the problem was the same

index.js

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const routes = require('./src/routes/routes');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(3009, () => {
    console.log('Listening on 3001...');
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

routes.js

```js
const checkErrors = require('../controllers/checkErrors');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/checkErrors', checkErrors);
module.exports = router;
```

And checkErrors.js

```js
const {TemplateHandler} = require('easy-template-x');
const handler = new TemplateHandler();
const busboy = require('busboy');

const checkErrors = async (req, res) => {
    const bb = busboy({headers: req.headers});
    let templateBuffer = null;
    let jsonData = '';

    bb.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
        file.on('data', (data) => {
            templateBuffer = data;
        });
    });

    bb.on('field', (fieldname, val) => {
        jsonData += val;
    });

    bb.on('finish', async () => {
        jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
        console.log(jsonData);
        const templateTags = await handler.parseTags(templateBuffer);
        const templateTagsNames = templateTags.map(({name}) => name);

        //Znajdź brakujące wartości w Excel i je zidentyfikuj
        const missingValues = [];
        jsonData
            .filter((row) => {
                return !templateTagsNames.every((name) => Object.keys(row).includes(name));
            })
            .forEach((row) => {
                templateTagsNames.forEach((templateName) => {
                    if (!row.hasOwnProperty(templateName)) {
                        missingValues.push({fieldName: templateName, rowNum: row.rowNum + 1});
                    }
                });
            });

        res.json({
            errors: missingValues,
        });
    });

    return req.pipe(bb);
};

module.exports = checkErrors;
```

Comment: What version you're using of busboy?

Comment: I'm using the ^1.6.0 version

Comment: Can you try to downgrade to v1.4.3. There's a known issue on 1.6.0 version > see this [link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/1144) for reference

Comment: I could not find v.1.4.3, so I installed v1.4.0 and the problem did not go away. Is there any way to upload a .docx file as a string and then convert it to Buffer on the server? Maybe this will allow me to bypass FormData

Comment: The error message suggests that the file being uploaded is not being parsed correctly by the `busboy` library. This could be due to the file being corrupted or incomplete, or an issue with the headers being sent with the request. To troubleshoot the issue, you can try checking the file, verifying the headers, using a different library for parsing the multipart form data, or enabling debug logs for `busboy`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today for several hours and tried just about everything to fix it. It seems there have been some breaking changes in Google Cloud / Firebase Functions which prevent express middleware from handling raw multipart data like it should. I found a different module which is able to handle this correctly.

Use [express-multipart-file-parser](https://github.com/cristovao-trevisan/express-multipart-file-parser) in your project instead of BusBoy. Here is an example:

```
const fileParser = require('express-multipart-file-parser')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { Readable } = require('stream');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");


const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(fileParser);
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/upload/', (req, res) => {
    const storage = admin.storage().bucket();

    const file = req.files[0];
    console.log(file); // you can see the file fields here, lots of good info from the parser

    // convert the file buffer to a filestream
    const fileStream = Readable.from(file.buffer);
    
    // upload to firebase storage
    const fileUpload = storage.file("/test/"+file.originalname);

    // create writestream with the contentType of the incoming file
    const writeStream = fileUpload.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
            contentType: file.mimetype
        }
    });
    
    // pipe the filestream to be written to storage
    fileStream.pipe(writeStream) 
      .on('error', (error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      })
      .on('finish', () => {
          console.log('File upload complete');
      });
});
```

I was really glad to finally come up with my own solution to this, as I couldn't find one anywhere on the internet as this seems like a recent change/issue with Firebase Functions. I hope this helps someone.

Don't forget to set up proper response codes, as this is just a demo solution. Also, don't trust the incoming original filename as it could be crafted maliciously.

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer to this is posted here:

[Firebase Cloud Function: "Unexpected end of form" error with multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75748741/firebase-cloud-function-unexpected-end-of-form-error-with-multipart-form-data)