# Error: Unexpected end of form > at Multipart._final

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, tensorflow.js

This is the first time I'm deploying a NodeJS/ExpressJS API to Firebase functions and I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Unexpected end of form
    at Multipart._final (/.../functions/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:588:17)
    at callFinal (node:internal/streams/writable:696:27)
    at prefinish (node:internal/streams/writable:725:7)
    at finishMaybe (node:internal/streams/writable:735:5)
    at Multipart.Writable.end (node:internal/streams/writable:633:5)
    at onend (node:internal/streams/readable:693:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

I'm trying to do is to send an image to the `/upload` end-point which takes the photo run it through `mobilenet` from Tensorflow and return the predictions array. My Code of `index.js` is:

```
const app = express();

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();

app.use(cors());

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
//#region Mobile Net Endpoint
let model;

mobilenet.load().then(loadedModel => {
    model = loadedModel;
    console.info('MobileNet model loaded successfully');
}).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error loading MobileNet model:', error);
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    // Handle the uploaded file here
    const file = req.file;

    if (!file) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No file uploaded' });
    } else if (file) {

        const readImage = () => {
            const imageBuffer = file.buffer;
            const tfimage = tfnode.node.decodeImage(imageBuffer);
            return tfimage;
        }

        const imageClassification = async () => {
            const image = readImage();
            const mobilenetModel = await mobilenet.load();
            const predictions = await mobilenetModel.classify(image);
            return res.json({ predictions });
            // console.log('Classification Results:', predictions);
        }

        imageClassification().then((pred) => {
            console.log("pred: ", pred);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("error: ", error);
            return res.status(400).json({ message: error });
        })

    }
});
//#endregion
```

I don't want to store the image in firebase storage or others that is why there is no implementation of that. I wanted the image to stay in `tmp` folder while the predictions are being calculated by mobile net. It works on `localhost` where the image is stored in my hard drive so not sure what I'm doing wrong for firebase functions here.

Comment: Have you tried downgrading `multer` to either `1.4.2` or `1.4.3` based on this [Github issue link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/1144)?

Comment: @RobertG looks like this might just solve the issue however I'm sending the file in the body with a `key: file` and value is the image.png I'm attaching on postman. When I `console.log(req.body)` I see `req.body:  [Object: null prototype] {}` which basically returns `No file uploaded`. So basically the `req.file` is `undefined` which I'm not sure why.

Comment: I've noticed that this is still an ongoing issue and there are several workarounds that may work with your project. In case that those workarounds still won't work, you may file this as a bug by adding a reply through the Github link that I previously sent or through [Firebase Bug Report](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs).

Answer (score 3):

There are several factors that may cause `Error: Unexpected end of form at Multipart._final...`:

- There's an ongoing issue with `Multer` and some users suggested downgrading to either `1.4.2` or `1.4.3` as mentioned in this [Github issue link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/1144).
- Some also mentioned that they used `body-parser` middleware as mentioned in this [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72544409/unexpected-end-of-form-error-when-using-multer).
- Another [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75748741/firebase-cloud-function-unexpected-end-of-form-error-with-multipart-form-data) stated that defining the file as `req.body` works out for them.

These are some of the workarounds that worked out. In case that the aforementioned workarounds didn't resolve the issue, I would suggest to file a bug through either of the links below:

- [Google Cloud issue tracking system and product feature requests](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)
- [Firebase bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs)
- [Multer Github issue link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues)